# Is there any difference between nevertheless and never the less?

Tags: differences, adverbs

I saw this on eBay's website:

> You can sell multiple items that, even though they are against eBay
>   policy, don’t get you caught.  **Never the less**, they are against the
>   rules and can result in you losing your eBay account.

Is **never the less** the formal version of **nevertheless**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Nevertheless* is a [conjunctive adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb):

> : in spite of that : however <her childish but *nevertheless* real delight — Richard Corbin>
>
> —source [Mirriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nevertheless)

*Never the less* is probably a typo. When it appears as three separate words, it means something quite different. One valid way of using this three-word phrase would be:

> You should always select the container that is more full, *never the less*.

A quick [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nevertheless,%20never%20the%20less&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) search shows that *never the less* is quite rare.